# out-of-order handling of messages in Kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I recently came across this article on Apache Kafka documentation regarding Handling of out of order messages in Kafka streams

https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/core-concepts#streams_out_of_ordering

Can someone explain me the reason behind the below statement :

> Within a topic-partition, a record's timestamp may not be monotonically increasing along with their offsets. Since Kafka Streams will always try to process records within a topic-partition to follow the offset order, it can cause records with larger timestamps (but smaller offsets) to be processed earlier than records with smaller timestamps (but larger offsets) in the same topic-partition.

As per my understanding, if messages in a single partition are produced by a single producer, their timestamp must be in nondecreasing order. How come messages are not in monotonically increasing order?

Comment: Here, messages' timestamps can be in monotonically increasing order. But it says, **may not be** in monotonically increasing order **along with their offsets**.

Answer (score 2):

A Kafka Producer may specify a timestamp when it produces a message.

An example with the standard Java Producer API:
https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html#ProducerRecord-java.lang.String-java.lang.Integer-java.lang.Long-K-V-

Comment: I know that. I don't understand that the messages with smaller timestamp can  be processed before messages with larger timestamp.

Comment: If you publish message with timestamp "today", it will get offset "X", and then you publish another message with timestamp "yesterday", it will get offset "X+1".  The message "today" will be consumed before the message "yesterday".  What is wrong is your assumption "their timestamp must be in nondecreasing order.": this is wrong because the timestamps can be manually set.

Comment: It is also possible, that multiple producers write into a single topic partition. This can also lead to out-of-order data. If there is only one producer, and the user code does not set the timestamp explicitly, the producer will set current system time. This way, no out-of-order data will be in the topic. The problem is, that when you consume a topic, there is no guarantee that the data was written that way.

Comment: So, By that explanation.. if there's only a single producer and we aren't setting any explicit timestamp, the messages will always have a nondecreasing timestamp and the messages will be consumed in the exact order in which they were written to the topic within the same partition?

Comment: If it is a single producer, yes It will be consumed in the same order.

Comment: There are still some corner cases: for example, you would need to set in-flight request on the producer to 1, or enable idempotent writes. Otherwise, in error scenarios the producer might re-order messages...